# Area 51 allows users to commit to a closed proposal

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, commitment-phase, closed-proposals

The [Apocalyptic Defense](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2868/apocalyptic-defense) proposal has been closed as "not a real proposal". This, however, did not stop me from committing to it. Unless I misunderstood the purpose of the close mechanism, this seems like unintended behavior.

Comment: Closed? *Dang* it - the Men In Black must have... gotten to the moderators... On a serious note - if the moderators are going to close proposals they don't like, why even let it get this far? Close them from the start, like they will presumably *also* do to the Conspiracy Theory site...

Comment: I assume it was left open because we are in beta @john

Comment: @Juan Manuel: You would be correct. Apocalyptic Defense was fun but I had to do a bit of clean up prior to our public announcement coming up very shortly.

Comment: @Juan a heads up from head honcho that the close hammer were comming would have been nice.

Comment: It was the *Men In Black*, I tell you... :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the intended behavior. Closing a proposal is analogous to closing a question. You can still vote on it and it can be voted to re-open. Eventually, closed proposals will be deleted.

**Update**

We changed our mind on this.  Following / Committing are different than normal voting, so you won't be able to follow / commit to a closed proposal, and a commitment on a closed proposal won't count against your commitment limit.

Comment: Closing in the definition phase makes sense, but what's the point of closing in the commitment phase if people can still commit, presumably to the point at which the site would go into beta?

Comment: @kyle, not a real proposal won't make it to commit before being closed in the future; now it's in beta.

Comment: @Kyle: A closed proposal can still receive "votes" (a closed proposal is not deleted, it can be re-opened) but it will not pass on to the next phase.

Comment: I don't get it.  It was pretty obvious where this site was going from day one.  It's not like the site was bitten by a zombie after 10 days and, only then, did you finally realize you had to "remove the head or destroy the brain".  Why let people waste so much time with it before you put the kibosh upon it?

Comment: Did anyone actually think it would **not** be closed? It was a silly beta proposal. People had fun with it, but I hope noone was counting on it actually getting created as a real site!

Comment: @Raven, in the beta phase they are testing all the mechanisms. Proposals like "Apocalyptic Defence", because they are fun by nature, will draw a lot of attention, and this enables the dev team to test their functionality. However, the "test data" that you use in the beta phase should be expunged before you go live. Even if people like the test data.

Comment: Thanks for getting this done so quickly :)