# Please annul this relationship, I can't remain committed to a partner that won't move forward!

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, commitment-phase, uncommit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow users to un-commit from locked proposals in the commitment phase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53798/allow-users-to-un-commit-from-locked-proposals-in-the-commitment-phase)

I can't stand being committed to a [locked proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2868/apocalyptic-defense-closed) (especially since it 'eats' one of my 3 possible engagements).

If this relationship cannot continue, for whatever reason, I request that Area51 allow me to be divorced from it.

- Please enable the Uncommit button for locked proposals

I assume it's enabled for closed proposals, but please check to make sure...

Comment: What about a `Trial Separation` button, if you're not sure?

Comment: @Michael - Honestly this stems from the idea that a *little* polygamy is ok, but *not too much* - I mean, really, why put an artificial limit on **love**?

Comment: I hate to do this to such a question, but allowing the ability to uncommit from a locked proposals [is already requested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53798/allow-users-to-un-commit-from-locked-proposals-in-the-commitment-phase)...

Comment: @ccomet - I like my version better, so I'm closing his as a duplicate of mine.

Comment: It seems like a simple query at this point could set 35 people free. Irreconcilable differences here as well.

Comment: @Pol - your love may be infinite, but is your bank account?

Comment: Your annulment has been granted! Mine too :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Back in *my* day, commitment actually *meant* something. When you committed, you *stayed* committed, 'cause the thought of "uncommitting" negated the very idea of commitment!

Nowadays, 'seems "commitment" is just another empty word, bandied around by soulless hipsters, to be disingenuously embraced one moment only to be tossed aside the next, like some ripped and faded bowling league t-shirt bought for $1.13 at Goodwill.

Well, you can just *rot* in that t-shirt. 'Cause Life ain't all *fairs and carny games*, sunny. When the Apocalypse hits, you're not gonna be able to *opt out*, or sit on your porch drinking PBR and *just watching*. There ain't gonna be no *choice* in the matter, and little whiners who can't hack it 'l be the first tasty meals for the *demon hordes*. You'll be *committed* whether you like it or not, and you *won't* like it, and it *won't* matter.

Ya best just get used to it now...

Comment: But if we don't toss our commitments aside, what will the hipsters wear?  Heaven forbid they should walk around naked!

Comment: I agree, it's just like your t-shirt.

Comment: Commitment isn't a the *perfect* analogy. Commitment is more like buying a ticket to an event. If they sell enough tickets, they can pretty much guarantee the event's success (or cancel it if there is insufficient interest). That doesn't *obligate* you to go. If you would prefer to go to another event, you can return your ticket and use that "money" to purchase a different ticket.

Comment: @Aarobot: actually, I put my $1.13 toward a used t-shirt branded by the company *that I actually work for*. It's ironically sincere... I think.

Comment: @Shog9: I think the word you meant was "sonny" not "sunny"  slightly different meanings.

Comment: @Chris: Pollyanna is well known for her sunny disposition ;-)

Comment: @Robert that's the reason for a "no refund" statement in the fine print - you don't have to go, but anyway they got the money to organize it

Comment: @Tobias: We don't have "no refund" fine print. If you aren't going to use the site (or if you'd rather "commit" to another site), un-commit.

Comment: @Robert I was referring to your event ticket analogy. And I will only commit to something from which I won't wish to un-commit. I consider commitment a promise, not a checkbox.

Comment: @RobertCartaino is there no cost or penalty involved with un-committing as you mention above in your "We don't have 'no refund' fine print." comment?

Answer (score 6):

Clearly, this is your punishment for participating in a joke proposal.  Remember the First Rule of Stack Exchange:

> **Don't cross Jeff.**

EDIT:
Okay, despite the humorous language, the OP asked a serious question.  So here is a serious answer.  If the proposal is going to be locked or deleted, why stop at an <kbd>uncommit</kbd> button?  The system might as well automatically uncommit all followers, in case they don't notice the status of the proposal for a while.  I say this because I can't imagine any proposal ever returning to active status after reaching locked or deleted status, even though the possibility is *technically* open.  Forcing people to manually uncommit is an annoyance at best and rubbing salt in the wound at worst.

Comment: No, the first rule is "Do not talk about Jeff".

Comment: But the proposal is a soul sucking [redacted at recommendation of divorce lawyer]!!!!

Comment: @gnovices, I was wondering how long it would be before someone posted that comment.  You have exceeded my expectations.  +1.

Comment: It ***wasn't*** a joke proposal. All of us fully intended on growing and maintaining the site.

Comment: @Tim - Zombie and raptor questions?  Not a joke?  The proposal may not have been a joke, but the site definition most certainly was - this is what the proposal turned into, regardless of the original intent.

Comment: @Pollyanna - A "joke" proposal is pushing something through just to say that you did, with no intention of actually maintaining a community. This was not a "joke" proposal. The highest voted example questions were a bit silly, yes, however the proposal itself was genuine. There is a difference, nobody here was playing a prank. We just wanted a place to be creative, unwind and entertain (sometimes) serious questions and discussions.

Comment: @Pollyanna - I can name much bigger sites that many consider to be a waste of bandwith, cpu cycles, power and time that get millions of visits per day.

Comment: @Tim, since when has "bad things exist" been a legitimate justification for "I want to create a bad thing"?

Comment: @Popular Demand - Since when has 'bad' been objective in this context?