# Now that Compiler Design is closed ... how do I uncommit?

Tags: support, area-51, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow users to un-commit from locked proposals in the commitment phase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53798/allow-users-to-un-commit-from-locked-proposals-in-the-commitment-phase)

How do I uncommit from [Compiler Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7848/compiler-design)?

Since it's closed, there's no point staying committed.

Comment: Bah, it is and always will be a dupe of [Please annul this relationship, I can't remain committed to a partner that won't move forward!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53880/please-annul-this-relationship-i-cant-remain-committed-to-a-partner-that-wont)!

Comment: @Kenny: This isn't a locked proposal. Nor is it resolved.

Comment: @George: See [Roberts answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53798/allow-users-to-un-commit-from-locked-proposals-in-the-commitment-phase/53897#53897). It applies to closed ones too.

Comment: @George Why do you need to uncommit? Closed proposals aren't included in your list of current commitments.

Comment: @Popular except that in this case, the proper wording would be "Please annul this relationship, I can't remain committed to a partner who was taken to the back yard and shot!" :D

Comment: I'm closing this because it's a dupe. But I think you need to edit the FAQ on Area51 to mention this

Comment: @Pekka, my __word__, you are dark.