# ability to unfollow a locked proposal thats in the commit phase

Tags: feature-request, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow users to un-commit from locked proposals in the commitment phase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53798/allow-users-to-un-commit-from-locked-proposals-in-the-commitment-phase)

So I can remove it from the "followed" list.

Comment: not uncommit, unfollow. I imagine there would be a different set of code changes for each.

Comment: @antony, take a look at Robert's answer.  He covers it all I believe.

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree, except that question has been marked as completed, and I am not able(or its not obvious how) to unfollow.

Comment: In theory, if a proposal you are following is closed, it should act *exactly* like you aren't following it. Either that, or you should be able to un-follow. I'm getting this clarified.

Comment: @Robert - it still shows up in my "follow" list.

Comment: @Robert re:@Polly as it does in mine too.

Comment: it drops to the bottom of the list, which is nice, but I'd like it either automatically not included or the ability to manually un-follow it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to uncommit or unfollow a locked/closed proposal, but as of now it no longer shows up in your "followed" or "committed" list. So, other than having your name show up on the proposal page, your following and/or commitment has no effect. But we'll remain open to the idea of allowing unfollowing/uncommitting, but not following/committing.

Comment: I'd like to be able to unfollow, but you're not going to get any proposals since the question got closed, which is a shame imo.